# Internally in Java primitive booleans are treated like -1?

Tags: java, programming-languages

The other day in a forum I was having a discusion about primitive booleans data types. And one guy said that in `ALL` languages `true` internally (or natively) is treated like  -1. Is this really the case?

PD: We were specially talking about Java

Comment: _All_ languages? I mean, it was true for the Win32 `BOOL` (and the VB `Boolean` by extension), sure, but I don't think you could say that _every single_ language has `-1` for `true`. Some languages don't even have a boolean type!

Comment: One guy in a forum always knows what he's talking about.

Comment: lol. You're right. That's why I made the question. because I don't beleve him and want to be sure.

Comment: @AndrésSánchez Actually you should accept the good answer you got.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is actually part of the JVM specification, at least in certain terms - and it's *not* -1. [Section 3.3.4](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/Overview.doc.html#22909) of the spec has this to say:

> Although the Java virtual machine defines a boolean type, it only provides very limited support for it. There are no Java virtual machine instructions solely dedicated to operations on boolean values. Instead, expressions in the Java programming language that operate on boolean values are compiled to use values of the Java virtual machine int 
>   data type.
>
> The Java virtual machine does directly support boolean arrays. Its newarray instruction enables creation of boolean arrays. Arrays of type boolean are accessed and modified using the byte array instructions baload and bastore.2
>
> The Java virtual machine encodes boolean array components using 1 to represent true and 0 to represent false. Where Java programming language boolean values are mapped by compilers to values of Java virtual machine type int, the compilers must use the same encoding.

As an example of this:

```
public static boolean returnFalse() {
    return false;
}

public static boolean returnTrue() {
    return true;
}
```

compiles to:

```
public static boolean returnFalse();
  Code:
     0: iconst_0
     1: ireturn

public static boolean returnTrue();
  Code:
     0: iconst_1
     1: ireturn
```

Answer (score 3):

No, this is not true. In C, any non-zero value will be interpreted as true in a boolean context, but operations like `==` and `&&` return 1 for true. In Python, `True` is distinct from any integer, but `True == 1` returns `True`; in older versions, `1` was used. I think `-1` is traditional in the BASIC family; certainly it was the case in QBasic and pre-.Net Visual Basic.

In Java, `true` is not "treated like" `-1` ... booleans and ints are separate types that can't be compared. The internal representation depends on the implementation.

Comment: Exactly, and I have used languages where only the final bit was used for true or false.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about `ALL` languages but in java boolean is distinct from numerical values.

Comment: They're probably handled as integers internally by the JVM.

Comment: They're most definitely stored as machine words, even if the JVM doesn't encode that explicitly.

Comment: Probably. I would love to learn about it. My comment was more about language semantics.

Comment: Well if you get down to it EVERYTHING is encoded as numerical values - but nobody would say that the string "HELLO" is interpreted internally in the JVM as.. well I'm too lazy to do the math but you get the idea ;)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the implementation of the JVM.

Answer (score 0):

The low-level internal representations of booleans is a platform specific issue.  However, since Java is normally (always?) implemented using C/C++, booleans are most likely represented the same way boolean values are handled in C/C++.  Namely, 0 is defined as `FALSE` and anything else is defined as `TRUE`.

Answer (score 0):

The -1 could be as a result of the two's complement value of -1 being all bits set.  The actual memory occupied is JVM-dependant and can be anything from a bit to a 32-bit integer.  As far as I recall, most JVMs model booleans as ints.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the only language I'm aware of that used -1 as true was VARIANT_BOOL by the Visual Basic folks. And they only did that because of limitations in the language (only having bitwise logical operations didn't turn out to be such a good idea I'd wager).