# Method should return boolean, returns int

Tags: java, methods, bytecode

I have to create a method similiar to one that's inside a JAR. I have no code, so I disassabled to study. 
I used JD-GUI, which tells me, is:

```
private static boolean checkMe(Date paramDate, String paramString)
        throws REUException {
    int i = 1;
    int j, k;

    // unrelated stuff

    if (j > k)
        i = 0;
    return i;
}
```

You can see in method signature it should return a `boolean`, but it really returns an `ìnt`, which is not allowed in Java
So, I thought there were something wrong with JD-GUI.

I tried to dissasemble using `javap`, but I still don't get a clue:

Using: `javap -c -s -verbose -private Class`

I get:

```
private static boolean checkMe(java.util.Date, java.lang.String)   throws reu.exceptions.REUException;
  Signature: (Ljava/util/Date;Ljava/lang/String;)Z
  Code:
   Stack=4, Locals=7, Args_size=2
   0:   iconst_1
   1:   istore_2
   2:   getstatic   #34; //Field iniciado:Z
   5:   ifne    44
   8:   ldc_w   #35; //class reu/modulos/STDWDATES
   11:  dup
   12:  astore_3
   13:  monitorenter
   14:  getstatic   #34; //Field iniciado:Z
   17:  ifne    32
   20:  new #35; //class reu/modulos/STDWDATES
   23:  dup
   24:  invokespecial   #36; //Method "<init>":()V
   27:  pop
   28:  iconst_1
   29:  putstatic   #34; //Field iniciado:Z
   32:  aload_3
   33:  monitorexit
   34:  goto    44
   37:  astore  4
   39:  aload_3
   40:  monitorexit
   41:  aload   4
   43:  athrow
   44:  aconst_null
   45:  getstatic   #37; //Field AlmacenFechaCal:Ljava/util/HashMap;
   48:  aload_1
   49:  invokevirtual   #38; //Method java/util/HashMap.get:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
   52:  if_acmpne   67
   55:  new #39; //class reu/exceptions/REUException
   58:  dup
   59:  bipush  58
   61:  bipush  17
   63:  invokespecial   #40; //Method reu/exceptions/REUException."<init>":(II)V
   66:  athrow
   67:  getstatic   #37; //Field AlmacenFechaCal:Ljava/util/HashMap;
   70:  aload_1
   71:  invokevirtual   #38; //Method java/util/HashMap.get:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
   74:  checkcast   #41; //class reu/modulos/AlmancenFechas
   77:  astore_3
   78:  aload_3
   79:  invokevirtual   #42; //Method reu/modulos/AlmancenFechas.getFechaIni:()I
   82:  istore  4
   84:  invokestatic    #43; //Method java/util/Calendar.getInstance:()Ljava/util/Calendar;
   87:  astore  5
   89:  aload   5
   91:  aload_0
   92:  invokevirtual   #44; //Method java/util/Calendar.setTime:(Ljava/util/Date;)V
   95:  aload   5
   97:  iconst_1
   98:  invokevirtual   #45; //Method java/util/Calendar.get:(I)I
   101: istore  6
   103: iload   4
   105: iload   6
   107: if_icmple   112
   110: iconst_0
   111: istore_2
   112: iload_2
   113: ireturn
  Exception table:
   from   to  target type
    14    34    37   any
    37    41    37   any
  Exceptions: 
   throws reu.exceptions.REUException
```

I guess clue is `ireturn` expression in 113. According to [oracle documentation for `ireturn`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.ireturn), it returns an int.

In this [Casting conversions to primitive types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.5), looks like a conversion from int to boolean, unlike C/C++,  is not allowed.

How is that possible? Is there an implicit cast?

Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't compile for me. Should be a problem with your compiler.

Comment: It shouldn't compile.. Most narrowing conversions will give a compile time error in java.

Comment: See this answer for explanation and examples http://stackoverflow.com/a/8249193/2595658

Comment: @TheLostMind I know it doesn't compile. That's why a make the question. I'm showing the code decompiled from a class within a JAR.

Comment: @Mints97, same answer for you :)

Comment: Also, JD-GUI is not a very good decompiler. Why not use Luyten instead? That will also infer booleans for you.

Comment: @Antimony Never heard of it. I'll have a look on it.  Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The JVM uses integers to represent booleans. From the [JVM Specification  §2.3.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.3.4):

> **2.3.4. The boolean Type**
>
> Although the Java Virtual Machine defines a boolean type, it only provides very limited support for it. There are no Java Virtual Machine instructions solely dedicated to operations on boolean values. Instead, expressions in the Java programming language that operate on boolean values are **compiled to use values of the Java Virtual Machine int data type**.

You can check this out your self:

```
$ cat Test.java
class Test {
    boolean m() {
        return true;    <------------
    }
}
$ javac Test.java 
$ javap -c Test
Compiled from "Test.java"
class Test {
  [...]     

  boolean m();
    Code:
       0: iconst_1      
       1: ireturn        <------------
}
```

Comment: OP found a class and used a decompiler to get the Java code. The *original* Java code was most likely valid (using booleans and not ints).

Comment: @aioobe. I understand, it means JD-GUI has some kind of bug. Nevertheless, is weird because I decompiled your example with JD-GUI (using a variable), and it shows:   `boolean m()  {boolean bool = false; return bool; }`, which is correct.

Comment: That's interesting. I agree that since it got the return type of the method right, it should definitely have been smart enough to figure out that `i` originally was a `boolean`.

Comment: Yes. Now it's just curiosity. If I'm able to locate them, I'll try to inform project about this possible "bug" or use another decompiler. Thanks.

Comment: Right. That's a good habit and friendly act as a fellow programmer :-)

Comment: It’s likely that the decompiler started at the beginning of the method, encountering variable #2 which looked like an `int` variable and its relationship to the `ireturn` wasn’t revealed yet. And on encounter of the `ireturn`, it did not revise the type of the variable.

Comment: Well, it revised the type in a simpler example (see Alberts comment above) so I'd still say it's a bug.

Comment: @aioobe: in this example, no local variable is involved at all. I would consider the fact that the decompiler introduces an unnecessary new local variable where none existed as *another* (not so critical) bug. But even if there was a local variable involved, being able to understand the situation when it is introduced right before the return instruction is not contradicting to the inability to revise the guessed variable type when the relationship is revealed after processing in-between code.

Comment: Albert used a variable in his test.

Comment: @aioobe: Ok, but the statement about the difference between a variable introduced right before the return instruction and having lots of code between the variable’s introduction and the return instruction still holds. After all, even bugs follow logical patterns and I think, this one is obvious.

Comment: @Holger, I added some trivial stuff, between `boolean` variable declaration and its return. JD-GUI still shows it as `boolean`. It shows exactly what I typed, except variable names: `boolean m(String paramString) {boolean bool = false; paramString = paramString + "Test";  bool = (paramString != null) && (paramString.length() > 1); return bool;}`. I didn't test on another decompiler yet, as Antimony suggested, but I will.

Comment: Something's not right. Without the source code of JD-GUI, all we can do is speculate. I see little point in doing this.

Comment: There is no source code for JD-Core, which is the library that JD-GUI uses to decompile. I mean, it is not available... obviously exists ;)

Comment: Yes. I'm aware of that. :-/

Answer (score 4):

The JVM represents `boolean`s as `int`s: `true` is represented by `1` and `false` by `0`. That's why the compiled code uses integers.

In other words, if you write that method and use `boolean`s as follows (which probably what the original source was):

```
private static boolean checkMe(Date paramDate, String paramString)
       throws REUException {
   boolean i = true;
   int j, k;

    // unrelated stuff

    if (j > k)
        i = false;
    return i;
}
```

then the generated bytecode would contain `ireturn` at the end.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, I don't have access to source code.  I already tried what you says: compile the code you provide, and then decompile, and it shows `i` as `boolean`, not `int`. That's what I don't understand and that's why I asked.

Comment: Then it may be a bug in the JD-GUI decompiler itself.

Comment: Yes. I guess there is no other option. I'll try to report it to them. Thanks.